# Term for code that has a strict interface but is weakly typed

Tags: php, terminology

Is there a term or a phrase that describes code that is strict about types, in the sense that no method returns multiple types and no parameter accepts multiple types, but is written in a weakly typed language like PHP?

I have a library that is like that and I'm looking for a way to express that.

Comment: I suggest `type-safe`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks! You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a term or a phrase that describes code that is strict about
>   types, in the sense that no method returns multiple types and no
>   parameter accepts multiple types,

Yes it's called 'type-safety'. I believe you can accept arrays and return arrays in different languages to avoid this though.

> but is written in a weakly typed language like PHP?

Not any that I can think of. In a weakly typed language like php you can still force the params to be either [objects, arrays and call backs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Now to emulate type safety in php you can do something similar to this:

```
function myFunction( $param1, $param2 ) {
    if( (is_string( $param1 )) && (is_string( $param2 )) ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // throw error or custom string exception
    }
}
```